# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException в question mark operator

Tags: java

При компиляцию выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. 
Не понимаю что это такое и как решить проблему.

Comment: При компиляции чего? Кто выдает? Точно компиляции, а не запуске?